# localhost apache2 not working after change default path on ubuntu desktop 22.04

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, localhost, apache2

I have installed apache2, php, mariadb, phpmyadmin to Ubuntu 22.04.

All was working fine than I changed default www path to new folder path "/home/user/www".

For this I did following steps

1. in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf I changed DocumentRoot /home/user/www
2. in apache2.conf I changed

> < Directory />
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
> AllowOverride All
> Require all denied
> < /Directory>

to

> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
>      AllowOverride All
>      Require all granted

And added

> <Directory /home/user/www>Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
> AllowOverride All     Require all denied < /Directory>

3. 

```
sudo adduser user www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/user/www/
sudo chmod -R g+rw /home/user/www/

sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

And I am getting error when I go to 'localhost'

[image]

"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80"

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's due to `new directive` of `apache2` with `ubuntu 22.04.3-LTS`

1. You need to edit: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
2. Then, at the end of file add: `ServerName 127.0.1.1`
3. Go to: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
4. Change`DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to-> `/home/user/www/`
5. After that: `sudo apachectl configtest`
6. You should get a result of: `Syntax OK`
7. Fianlly, restart apache: `systemctl restart apache2`

I made my symbolic link to `/home/user/www`

`ln -s /home/YourName/www` ( Important !) `Without sudo!`

***`Ubuntu 22.04`***

But it's different on `ubuntu 22.04`:

1. You need to edit: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
2. Then, at the end of file add: `ServerName localhost`
3. Go to: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
4. change path `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to -> `/var/www`
5. After that: `sudo apachectl configtest`
6. You should get a result of: `Syntax OK`
7. Fianlly, restart apache: `systemctl restart apache2`

I made my symbolic link to `/home/user/www`

`ln -s /home/YourName/www` ( Important !) `Without sudo`

That's done, good Programming days!